# Kafka/Confluent: ProducerConfig change default max.request.size using docker images

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm using kafka/confluent (3.2.0) to retrive change on a Mongodb instances we have.

The source process is managed by [Debezium source connector](http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mongodb/) who uses Source Connect  Api and is deployed on our systems using Mesos (DC/OS) expanding the Confluent Connect docker image.
Kafka itself is deployed on the same DC/OS using the framework version.

Since we've some message bigger than default size I've changed these kafka installation parameters:

•   replica.fetch.max.bytes
•   message.max.bytes

both to 4MB.

Then I start the Connector Docker image using this

```
docker run -d --rm --net=bridge --name=kafka-connect-mongodb -e CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=${KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS} -e CONNECT_REST_PORT=${CONNECT_REST_PORT}  -e CONNECT_GROUP_ID="mongo-to-kafka-source-connector" -e CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC="${CONFIG.TOPIC}"  -e CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC="${OFFSETS.TOPIC}"   -e CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC="${STATUS.TOPIC}"   -e CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER="io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"   -e CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER="io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"   -e CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL="${SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS}"   -e CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL="${SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS}"   -e CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"   -e CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"   -e CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME="${CONNECTOR_HOME}"   -e CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL=INFO  -e CONNECT_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE=4194304 -e KAFKA_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE=4194304  mongodb-source-connector:1.1
```

I changed the default max.request.size producer value passing both KAFKA_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE and CONNECT_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE and the log was properly changed to 4MB.

The issue arises when I start the extraction from Mongodb. 
To do so i run this POST

```
curl -X POST \  
http://hostname:8083/connectors \
  -d '{ 
  "name": "source_connector",  
  "config": {
    "tasks.max":"1",
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector", 
    "mongodb.hosts": "mongodbhost:27017", 
    "mongodb.name": "replica", 
    "collection.whitelist": "db[.]table",
    "max.request.size": "4194304"
  }
}'
```

but then the log says

```
[2017-10-09 12:22:56,036] INFO ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = all
    batch.size = 16384
    block.on.buffer.full = false
    bootstrap.servers = [PLAINTEXT://172.17.0.3:9093]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.id = 
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    interceptor.classes = null
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 9223372036854775807
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 1
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 2147483647
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    timeout.ms = 30000
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
```

So when i start the source process, the default value for max.request.size is used.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfszid94ot8pfud/log.log?dl=0) the full log.

I don't undestand what i miss.

Answer (score 10):

the IRC chat helped me:
i had to specify both 
KAFKA_PRODUCER_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE
and
CONNECT_PRODUCER_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE
while starting the docker image.